# Drawing shape using opengl

Tags: opengl

how can i draw  shape like (sin) if i describe the shape like half circle closed and the other half circle connected with the first one.  using Cartesian method this is my trying:

```
#include <windows.h>   
#include <gl/Gl.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<cstdlib>

 static void myDisplay()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the screen
      glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
       glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
          glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

         double xc=200, yc=200,r=100;
            double x,y;

            for (x = xc - r; x<= xc + r;x++)
           {
            y = sqrt((r*r)-((xc - x)*(xc - x)));
            glVertex2d(x, yc + y);

           }

            for (x = xc +r ; x<= xc - r ; x++)
            {
            y = sqrt((r*r)-((xc - x)*(xc - x)));

            glVertex2d(x , yc - y);
            }


        glEnd();

        glFlush();
      }
void myInit(void)
{
glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);       // set white background color
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);          // set the drawing color 
glPointSize(4.0);              // a ‘dot’ is 4 by 4 pixels
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0.0, 640.0, 0.0, 480.0);
}    

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);          // initialize the toolkit
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); // set display mode
glutInitWindowSize(640,480);     // set window size
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150); // set window position on screen
glutCreateWindow("Line Scan Conversion"); // open the screen window
glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);     // register redraw function
myInit();

glutMainLoop();              // go into a perpetual loop
}
```

Comment: What is the problem in your code?

Comment: the first half circle drawing but the second half (Beside) the first i don't know to do it

Comment: Just draw separate half circle objects, and flip the second half circle upside down. Simple sin/cos circle function all you need. If i understood you correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Just sample the function (`sin()`) directly:

[image: sin]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>

static void myDisplay()
{
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );       // set white background color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the screen

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -0.5, 7, -1.2, 1.2, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();

    // axes
    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );
    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    glVertex2i( 0, 0 );
    glVertex2i( 7, 0 );
    glVertex2i( 0, -1 );
    glVertex2i( 0, 1 );
    glEnd();

    // sin() function plot
    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    const unsigned int samples = 100;
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i <= samples; ++i )
    {
        const float pct = ( (float)i / samples );
        const float x = 2 * 3.14159 * pct;
        const float y = sin( x );
        glVertex2f( x, y );
    }
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);          // initialize the toolkit
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB); // set display mode
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);     // set window size
    glutCreateWindow("Line Scan Conversion"); // open the screen window
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);     // register redraw function
    glutMainLoop();              // go into a perpetual loop
}
```

Comment: please understand me i can't loading image because my reputation is little    i want like sin not sin but similar the sin put the the first half circle up must be closed and half circle Down must be closed too using the Cartesian method

Comment: @ genpfault  the first half circle drawing but the second half (Beside) the first i don't know to do it

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your second `for` loop:

`for( x = xc + r; x <= xc - r; x++ )`

this is being executed as `x = 400; x <= 0; x++` which clearly will never run. Your issue (other than the obvious pointed out above) is that you are trying to account for the `x` offset in the loop iterations. I suggest changing to the following:

`for( x = 0; x < 2r; x++ )`

and then instead of

`glVertex2d(x, yc + y);`

`glVertex2d(x, yc - y);`

do

`glVertex2d((xc - r) + x, yc + y);`

`glVertex2d((xc + r) + x, yc - y);`

or something similar (not in a position to actual test this, but you should get the idea).

Comment: @ ssell please the for( x = 0; x < 2r; x++ ) instead of first and second loop or what ??

Comment: I would make your drawing code resemble: `for( x = 0; x < 2r; x++ ){ y = sqrt((r*r)-((xc - x)*(xc - x))); glVertex2d((xc - r) + x, yc + y); }` for the first half, and then `for( x = 0; x < 2r; x++ ){ y = sqrt((r*r)-((xc - x)*(xc - x))); glVertex2d((xc + r) + x, yc - y); }` for the second half.